# Wrap items in columns of unequal height

Tags: html, css

The items need to arrange in columns based on max column height, like this

```
item 1 | item 6
item 2 | 
item 3 |
item 4 |
item 5 |
```

I tried using this column css

```
ul {
    height: 150px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

but it arranges the items in columns of same height like this

```
item 1 | item 4
item 2 | item 5
item 3 | item 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to CSS3 columns, you could also use [CSS3 flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

Set the `display` of the parent element to `flex`, set `flex-direction` to `column` and then force it to wrap by adding `flex-wrap: wrap`.

The flexbox container element will respect the height, which seems to be what you're trying to achieve.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```